# VBA ClearContents initiates UserDefinedFunction update

Tags: vba, function

I am trying to clear the contentents of some cells and it is causeing the program to crash. While stepping through the code using the debugging tool the line

```
Range(light.Offset(0, 4), light.Offset(0, 9)).ClearContents
```

executes and then I step and instead of executing the next line of code, the debugger jumps to the function call:

```
Function overhaulCosts(buoyName As Range, district As String, orgComSplit As Range)
```

I know user defined functions are updated whenever cells that reference them are changed, but in this case none of the cells that are being cleared use the function or are referenced by a cell that uses that function. Does a ClearContents call in a workbook always trigger a user defined function call?

Comment: It sounds like the real problem is that the UDF is crashing the application. Trying to work around that will only get you so far. Its better to tackle it now instead of pursuing these small fixes.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it is triggering 'Application.Calculate'. I believe you can stop this by temporarily disabling automatic calculations.

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Range(light.Offset(0, 4), light.Offset(0, 9)).ClearContents
Application.Calculation =xlCalculationAutomatic
```